# Exception handling for flow control ?

Tags: language-design

Is it appropriate to use Exception handling for flow control of our programs ?

There are some programming languages/circumstances where we can't avoid it Exception handling for flow control. Should we strictly avoid it?

Comment: I think this question may be more appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this question belongs to Stack Overflow.

I see two cons :

- Googleing "exceptions are slow" gives you results on Stack Overflow about various languages (.net, java). It seems that speed is not an issue, as long as exceptions don't happen *too* often.
- Like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions), "you really should recognize that using an exception for program flow is no better than using GOTOs". Whether GOTOs should be used or not is up to you, but relying only on them is surely going to make your code unmaintainable.